# How do I disconnect clients on my Mac file server from the command line

Tags: command-line, ventura, file-sharing

I have use a Mac mini (running Ventura) with a connected Drobo as a file server. The file sharing is standard Mac file sharing to other Macs via SMB. I believe AFP is no longer supported, or no longer the default.

It is set to restart, using `pmset`, on a schedule.

If a client computer has mounted the file share, then the file share computer fails to shut down.

How can I, from the command line (and hence from a `cron` job), ensure that all connected clients are forcibly disconnected?

Comment: how do the clients mount, via smb? Can you shutdown via `shutdown` instead of `pmset`?

Comment: @nohillside , the file server is Mac file sharing to other Macs via SMB. I believe AFP is no longer supported, or at least no longer the default.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`/sbin/shutdown` will shut down your Mac even with users logged in/server connections still open. To make sure your server shuts down at the appropriate time, you can run `/sbin/shutdown -t now` via `cron`.

PS: There is of course a slight risk of data loss in case a client is currently updating data on the server. But this can't be avoided if you want to shutdown forcefully.

Comment: Thanks. I think this has to be my route if there's no way to explicitly disconnect clients. In my mind, a shutdown via `pmset` seems more graceful (I suppose, hence the problem with connected clients) while `shutdown` seems drastic - somewhat like pulling the plug!

Comment: @Vihung Pulling the plug is worse. `shutdown` tries to end processes gracefully and ensures that pending writes get written to disk. But it can't ensure data consistence on application level (but then, no server-side approach can).